# ActiveModel::Model inheritance not working as expected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activemodel

I'm trying to use inheritance with the classical "type" attribute. On initialize User with type: "Admin" I expect an **Admin** object but it returns a **User** object. How can I make a class to act like a model and also make it act like it has STI?

```
class User
  include ActiveModel::Model
  attr_accessor :type

  def persisted?
    false
  end
end

class Admin < User
end
```

`user = User.new(type: "Admin")
 #=> #<User:0x007ff68a1ade60 @type="Admin">`

Comment: `type` is just an instance variable here. When you instantiate a new user and provide `type` it just sets that variable. `Admin.new` will give you an object of class `Admin`.

Answer (score 1):

```
class User
  include ActiveModel::Model

  def self.build(type: 'User')
    klass = Kernel.const_get(type)
    if klass.ancestors.include?(User)
      klass.new
    else
      raise "you are just not my type"
    end
  end

  def persisted?
    false
  end
end

class Admin < User
end

> u = User.build(type: 'Admin) # => instance of Admin
> u = User.build # => instance of User
> u = User.build(type: 'Object') # => RuntimeError
```

Comment: I think more is needed for subclasses to work with form_for